# Contour Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the complex integral $\int \sin(z)dz$ over the contour shown below.

[image]

The approach I took was to parametrize the semicircle and the line separately, obtaining $z(t)= 3e^{it}$ and $z(t)=3+3t+3it$ respectively.

However, when I'm going to solve the integrals these two functions become the argument of the $\sin(z)$ function. I don't know how to proceed form here. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: $\sin(z)$ is analytic with antiderivative $-\cos(z)$.  The integral depends only on the endpoints of the contour and hence $\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \sin(z)\,dz=\cos(z_1)-\cos(z_2)$

Comment: Dr. MV´s "comment" is, in fact, a complete and accurate answer. Analicity is a very powerful characteristic some complex functions have, and when they do sometimes things can get extremely easy.

Comment: Oh I understand! Thank you both for your help!